# what is the best method to fetch data on frontend in j2ee application?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am working on J2EE application, in which I am using JSP for front end programming, a servlet for processing and Mysql database. In my database, I have stored data regarding my project in a table with attributes like ( name, price, location, images, address, rating,)now I want to show that data on one of my web page. can anyone suggest me how to do this? what is the best way because I am new to this.

Comment: just use jdbc to execute querry in My Sql db and then get the result in ResultSet then you can send this object to jsp to same page or different web page you can use RequestDispacher

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JPA (Java Persistence API) do achieve this (Retrieving the data from the database server). Once your data has been retrieved you can set attributes on your HttpServletRequest object and then dereference the values in your JSP using JSTL.

Comment: You will need to lookup JPA tutorials that suite your needs (There are different providers etc). JSTL is a tag library used in conjunction with JSP to allow for data to be accessed on the JSP (data which has been set on the HttpServletRequest object). Try implementing and then ask as you implement... we will assist you as you implement...